# Any pitfalls using char* instead of void* when writing cross platform code?

Tags: c++, pointers, cross-platform

Is there any pitfalls when using char*'s to write cross platform code that does memory access?

UPDATE: For example, should I check before casting a dereferenced char* to a certain type (say an int) if address is aligned to the size of that type? Will certain architectures return strange results on unaligned access?

I'm working on a play memory allocator to better understand how to debug memmory issues. I have come to believe char*'s are preferable because of the ability to do pointer arithmetic and dereference them over void*'s, is that true? Do the following assumptions always hold true on different common platforms?

```
sizeof(char) == 1
sizeof(char*) == sizeof(void*)
sizeof(char*) == sizeof(size_t)
```

Comment: Unless you're dereferencing `char` instances you're going to have to cast both `char*` and `void*` to whatever type they point to.

Comment: Don't know if it's 'guaranteed' but in my experience the first 2 should be safe. The last one...??.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sizeof(char)==1` is definitely always true.

`sizeof(char *) == sizeof(void *)` is *probably* always true as well. The C standard requires that they have the same representation, which at least strongly implies the same size.

`sizeof(char *) == sizeof(size_t)` definitely cannot be depended upon -- I know of implementations for which it is false (and while they probably don't conform perfectly with the standard, this isn't one of their problems).

Comment: Thanks Jerry. Do you know a type that's always the same size as pointer size ( other than the pointer type that is :) )? For example it should be 32 bits on a 32 bit build and 64 on a 64 bit build. I was under the impression size_t was such a type.

Comment: @UberMongoose: first, note there's not even a requirement that pointers all be the same size. They usually will be, but it's not required. In most typical cases, `size_t` will be the same as well, but again, not guaranteed (and I know of at least a couple exceptions). MS (for one example) defines some types like INT_PTR (an integer the same size as a pointer), but that's far from universal. Probably about the best you can do is use a typedef in a configuration header, so you can modify if you get to a platform where you need to.

Comment: intptr_t? "The following type designates a signed integer type with the property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer"

Comment: @rici: Ah, just so. Excellent suggestion (and one I hadn't previously noticed).

Comment: In theory, intptr_t is "optional" but I haven't run into its absence yet.

Comment: @rici: Yeah, all the intXX_t (XX=32, 64, etc.) types are optional too -- but the only place they should really be missing is on a 1's complement or signed magnitude machine (neither of which is at all common).

Comment: @JerryCoffin - it's not so much 1's complement; it's whether the targeted size exists in the hardware. So on hardware with 9-bit bytes there's no `int8_t`. Which is why `int_least8_t` or `int_fast8_t` is a better choice.

Comment: @PeteBecker: In theory, yes. In reality, however, you can at least fine a *few* 1's complement machines if you look hard. Finding 9-bit bytes outside a museum is a little more difficult (though finding 12- or 16-bit bytes isn't quite as hard).

Comment: Would be nice to have *The C standard requires that they have the same representation, which at least strongly implies the same size.* explained (perhaps with a quote) What do you mean by *strongly implies* is there ambiguity?